# Python Simple Card Game to Learn Classes

Tags: python, class, oop, python-2.7

I am trying to create a simple card game to better understand OOP and classes.

The game is as follows: Two cards are dealt from a deck. Then a third card is dealt. If the third card is between the first two cards, then the player wins. If the third card is equal to either of the first two cards, or is outside of the set, then the player loses.

This is what I have so far:

```python
class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []

    def PopulateDeck(self):
        suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in range(2, 15):
                if rank == 11:
                    value = "Jack"
                elif rank == 12:
                    value = "Queen"
                elif rank == 13:
                    value = "King"
                elif rank == 14:
                    value = "Ace"

                self.deck.append(str(value) + " of " + suit)

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, rank, value):
        self.rank = rank
        self.value = value
        self.card = self.rank + self.value
```

I am having a difficult time with classes and OOP, and I'm not sure if this is a good start, or where I should go next. Much of this was created by reading other sources and examples. Can anyone please provide advice on what other classes I may want to make to run my game, and how those classes may interact with/inherit from each other? Thank you.

Comment: You aren't using your `Card` class. Did you mean `self.deck.append(Card(rank, value + " of " + suit))`? Also, don't forget to give `value` a default value for number cards: `else: value = str(rank)`. Also, what is `self.card = self.rank + self.value` supposed to do?

Comment: Due to the nature of this question, I suggest having this migrated this to Code Review SE. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is more of a code/approach review. A card game is a case for composition, not inheritance; the `Deck` contains `Card`s, but isn't in itself a type of `Card`, and vice versa.

I think you are duplicating information in the `Card`. Just store suit and rank, and use `__str__` to create `'x of y'`. You can also implement the [rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__):

```
class Card(object):

    FACES = {11: 'Jack', 12: 'Queen', 13: 'King', 14: 'Ace'}

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        value = self.FACES.get(self.rank, self.rank)
        return "{0} of {1}".format(value, self.suit)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.rank < other.rank
```

Now e.g. `str(Card(13, 'Clubs')) == "King of Clubs"`. This way you don't duplicate the `rank` and `value` in `card`.

Next, I think the `Deck` should incorporate the population generation in `__init__`; you can provide optional arguments for a non-standard deck. I have included two implementations; the commented-out version is a list comprehension using `itertools` to do the same job in one line. I also provide a function to pick `n` different random cards from `self.deck`.

```
from itertools import product 
import random

class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self, ranks=None, suits=None):
        if ranks is None:
            ranks = range(2, 15)
        if suits is None:
            suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
##        self.deck = [Card(r, s) for r, s in product(ranks, suits)]
        self.deck = []
        for r in ranks:
            for s in suits:
                self.deck.append(Card(r, s))

    def deal(self, n):
        return random.sample(self.deck, n)
```

Now the game is simple; you can deal three cards per hand, and compare the cards naturally (using e.g. `<`) because of the comparison methods.

```
deck = Deck()
hand = deck.deal(3)
print(" - ".join(map(str, hand)))
if min(hand[0], hand[1]) < hand[2] < max(hand[0], hand[1]):
    print("Winner!")
else:
    print("Loser.")
```

Comment: I think this answer might be a little bit too complex for somebody who doesn't yet have a solid grasp of how to finish his/her game.

Comment: @Andrey this is fairly straightforward; if the OP wants to learn Python OOP, getting to grips with magic methods is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

As @tobias_k have pointed out in the comments + some of my thoughts

```
class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        self.dealt = [] #Prevents from dealing the same card

    def PopulateDeck(self):
        suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in range(2, 15):
                if rank == 11:
                    value = "Jack"
                elif rank == 12:
                    value = "Queen"
                elif rank == 13:
                    value = "King"
                elif rank == 14:
                    value = "Ace"
                else:
                    value = str(rank)

                self.deck.append(Card(value, suit))

    def deal(self):
        #Randomly select card
        remaining_cards = [card for card in self.deck if card not in self.dealt]
        card_index = random.randrange(0, len(remaining_cards)-1)
        card = remaining_cards[card_index]
        self.dealt.append(card)
        return card



    def shuffle(self):
        self.dealt = []

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.card = str(self.rank) + " " + str(self.suit)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.rank == other.rank and self.suit == other.suit

def play():
    deck = Deck()
    card1 = deck.deal()
    card2 = deck.deal()
    card3 = deck.deal()

#And here you will compare the cards to see if the player wins or not. Not sure 
#what exact criterion you're using.

deck.shuffle() #And leave your deck nicely shuffled for next game

play()
```

[Random documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

I have not run this code, and it likely contains errors. But it is an illustration of what you can do.

Comment: You have a `TypeError` in `Card.__init__` and a `NameError` in `Card.deal`. Also, there are only 13 cards per suit (2-10, JQKA).

Comment: You should really take a little more care with the code you provide, I know you made a cautionary note, but it won't be very helpful if the code you provide does not work.  I made several edits to fix some outstanding errors.

Comment: @farmerjoe I think `card = random.choice(remaining_cards)` saves you some lines and makes the process clearer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe agreed, I think that is a better call, but I was more playing damage control on this answer than providing my own methodology, I felt my edits reflected the intent **Andrey** had

Comment: @farmerjoe ah, I see. Note that `Card.__eq__` needs to be implemented for `card in self.dealt` to work, though, and that `randint(a, b)` *includes* `b`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Indeed!  Good catch!  Serves me right for being so nit picky in the first place haha

Comment: @farmerjoe classic application of [Muphry's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphrys_law)!

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning opps using card games as i find that is most easy way to understand the concepts. I have come accross this code sometime back, but not sure about the link. I am pesting this code with few usefull comments. This may be helpful.

```
from random import shuffle
class Card:
    suits = ['spades', 'hearts',  'diamonds', 'clubs']
    values = [None, None, '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']

    def __init__(self, v, s):
        '''suits + values are ints'''
        self.value = v
        self.suit = s

    def __lt__(self, c2): # allows to compare two objects cards in this case
        if self.value < c2.value:
            return True
        if self.value == c2.value: # value is what user is putting while creating object of class
            if self.suit < c2.suit: # c2 is with what we are comapring
                return True
            else:
                return False
        return False

    def __gt__(self, c2): # allows to compare two objects cards in this case,
        if self.value > c2.value: # c2 is with what we are comapring
            return True
        if self.value == c2.value:
            if self.suit > c2.suit: # suits comes into picture if values are same suit number is given importance
                return True
            else:
                return False
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        v = self.values[self.value] + ' of ' + self.suits[self.suit]
        return v


# defining the class which represent the deck of card

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for i in range(2,15):
            for j in range(4):
                self.cards.append(Card(i,j))

        shuffle(self.cards)

    def rm_card(self):
        if len(self.cards) == 0:
            return  # if block it return to None object when condition is satisfied

        return self.cards.pop()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name # name of the player
        self.card = None # current card player holding
        self.wins = 0

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        name1 = input('p1 name ')
        name2 = input('p2 name ')
        self.deck = Deck()
        self.p1 = Player(name1)
        self.p2 = Player(name2)

    def wins(self, winner):
        w = "{} wins this round"
        w = w.format(winner)
        print(w)

    def draw(self, p1n, p1c, p2n, p2c):
        d = "{} drew {} {} drew {}"
        d = d.format(p1n, p1c, p2n, p2c)
        print(d)

    def play_game(self):
        cards = self.deck.cards  # self.deck = Deck() and cards = self.deck.cards is list of card
        print('Beginning War!!!')
        while len(cards) > 2:
            m = 'q to quit. Any' + ' key to play'
            response = input(m)
            if response == 'q':
                break
            p1c = self.deck.rm_card() # removing first card from deck by player 1
            p2c = self.deck.rm_card() # removing second card from deck by player 2
            p1n = self.p1.name
            p2n = self.p2.name
            self.draw(p1n, p1c, p2n, p2c)

            if p1c > p2c:
                self.p1.wins +=1
                self.wins(self.p1.name)
            else:
                self.p2.wins += 1
                self.wins(self.p2.name)

        win = self.winner(self.p1, self.p2)
        print("War is over. {} wins".format(win))

    def winner(self, p1, p2):
        if p1.wins > p2.wins:
            return p1.name
        if p1.wins < p2.wins:
            return p2.name




        return 'Its Tie!'
game = Game()
game.play_game()
```

Source: https://thecleverprogrammer.com/2020/10/04/card-game-with-python/